# Selecting a subset where a categorical variable (column) can have 2 values

Tags: r

My data consists of frequency tables listed under each other for different models and scenario's (ie variables). I want to make selections of this database to make graphs for each subset.
Most of my variables are categorical and texts (eg weather, scenario). I couln't find a way to allow multiple values from a categorical variable (mostly `%in% c()` is used for numbers). I tried the following:

```
ThisSelection <- subset (Hist, all_seeds==0 & weather == "normal" & scenario %in% c("intact","depauperate"))
```

which doesn't work and

```
ThisSelection <- subset (Hist, all_seeds==0 & scenario =="intact" | scenario =="depauperate")
```

which gives only "inatct" scenarios.

My apologies if the answer is simple here, I searched the web but couldn't find where I'm wrong, and I believe there must be an other way than turning string variable-values into numerical ones. I'm a starter in R...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first should work. Hesitate to suggest it but is your spelling of "depauperate" consistent (including case?):

```
Hist<-data.frame(all_seeds=0, weather=sample(c("normal","odd"),20,T),scenario=sample(c("intact","depauperate"),20,T))
ThisSelection <- subset (Hist, all_seeds==0 & weather == "normal" & scenario %in% c("intact","depauperate"))
ThisSelection


   all_seeds weather    scenario
1          0  normal      intact
3          0  normal      intact
4          0  normal      intact
5          0  normal depauperate
6          0  normal      intact
10         0  normal depauperate
14         0  normal      intact
15         0  normal      intact
```

Comment: It was spelled correctly... However, it seems I just looked at the 'head' of the output file, not the tail, and values were actually included. Sorry for that, have been looking at it quite some time though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about logical operators priority:

```
set.seed(3099627)
Hist <- data.frame(first=sample(letters[1:3], 20, rep=T), second=sample(letters[4:6], 20, rep=T))
subset (Hist, first=="a" & (second=="d" | second=="e"))

   first second
1      a      e
4      a      d
15     a      e
20     a      d

subset (Hist, first=="a" & (second %in% c("d", "e")))

   first second
1      a      e
4      a      d
15     a      e
20     a      d
```

Comment: `%any%` has higher priority than `&` (see `?Syntax`) so the OP's first solution was correct like @Troy pointed out, and the parenthesis you suggest he uses are not needed. Your answer is however helpful in showing what the OP did wrong in his second solution.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't double-check the priority. As a rule of thumb, I always put parentheses when in doubt. Thanks for the comment though.